# Regex.Replace hashtags but ignore apostrophe (

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following C# code to replace hashtags in HTML strings and it works good but it also replaces apostrophes since they encode as `&#39;`

The code replaces the #39 with the URL. 
Such as **Hamburger's** is now converted to `Hamburger&<a href\"Default.aspx?search=39">39</a>s`

How can I ignore apostrophes for the regex replace?

```
public String ReplaceHashTags(string strContent)
    {

        string strHashtags = @"#(\w+)";

        strContent = Regex.Replace(strContent, strHashtags,
        "<a href=\"Default.aspx?search=$1\">$1</a>");

        return strContent;
    }
```

Comment: You need to figure out exactly what you want to match. You probably actually want to only match if there is a space before the `#`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell the Regex to not match if the `#` is preceded by `&`:

```
var strHashtagPattern = @"(?<!&)#(\w+)";
```

If you want to exclude all possible special character escapes, a negative lookahead may be better:

```
var strHashtagPattern = @"(?!(?<=&)#[\w\d]+;)#(\w+)";
```